# Excel/VB - Finding a data in a row

Tags: vba, excel

Is my code below correct it always output the "Nothing is found" but I have a data which matches the DateTxt. Here is what I want to do below, I want it to find the current day and select its column and copy paste it in another workbook and worksheet, this is going to be same for the previous day. The date is in row 2 and moves in column.

```
Dim DateTxt As Date
DateTxt = CLng(Date)
...
With DataWB.Worksheets("Summary").Range("2:1")
     Set rng = .Find(What:=DateTxt, _
                    After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                    LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                    LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                    MatchCase:=False)
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        Application.Goto rng, True
        MsgBox "Value Found" + rng.Value
    Else
        MsgBox "Nothing found"
    End If
End With
```

Here is the sample data and output:
Workbook to get the data:

```
    A       B     C      D
1
2  Date   Sept5  Sept6  Sept7
3  Data1  Value1 Value2 Value3
4  Data2  Value4 Value5 Value6
```

In the destination Wokrbook I will just get the date and data of the current and previous day.

```
   A       B     C      
1
2  Date   Sept6  Sept7
3  Data1  Value2 Value3
4  Data2  Value5 Value6
```

Comment: Maybe include some sample data and desired output.

Comment: Seems like the cells which have `Sept5` are formatted as text?

Comment: Your code works OK here, provided "real" dates are in the cells.  Are they dates formatted as **mmmd** ?, or are they merely TEXT entries?  Also, your DateText = Clng(DATE) line. Clng is superfluous.  Since DateText is declared as being of type Date, the Long will be coerced back to a date anyway.  You could either omit the Clng, or just use Date as your What:= argument.

Comment: Dates are formatted as dd/mm/yyyy.

Comment: Are the cells you're searching in being populated by a formula? If so `LookIn:=xlFormulas, _` could be your culprit.

Comment: @Cham If dates are formatted as dd/mm/yyyy then the values you are showing in your example (Sept5, Sept6, Sept7) cannot possibly be dates.  Hence your Find method will never find them/

Answer (score 0):

In range.find the **What** field is text format.

Delete line:
`DateTxt = CLng(Date)`
This will run

and in line:
`MsgBox "Value Found" + rng.Value`
replace + to &, because you can't add string value to long value.

Comment: Still outputs nothing found. Changed + to & and deleted the line DateTxt = CLng(Date).